# RaTengo duda al raspar este sitio

Tags: scrapy

tengo pocos conocimientos con scrapy, aunque ya he podido raspar varias paginas, estoy tratando de raspar algunos retail de mi país, para facilitar las cosas a a la población a la hora de comparar los precios de los productos. y aquí esta mi problemas.

el scrape resppnde 200 al parecer esta todo bien, pero no entra a las páginas para hacer el raspado, aqui esta mi código.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from paris.items import ParisItem


class MercadoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'paris'
    allowed_domains = ['www.paris.cl']
    start_urls = ['https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-todas-las-tv',
                  'https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-smart-tv',
                  'https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-ultrahd',
                  'https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-curvo-oled',
                  'https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-monitores',
                  'https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-accesorios-soportes-y-cables',
                  'https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-accesorios-tv-home-theater',
                  'https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-accesorios-tv-bluray-dvd']
    rules = {
        # Para cada item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[contains(@class,"load-more-products")]'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="itemPromo"]')),
                            callback='parse_item',  follow=False)
    }



    def parse_item(self, response):
        ml_item = ParisItem()
        ml_item['title1'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//h1[@class="detalles-titulo"]/text())').extract_first()
        ml_item['precio_normal'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//p[@class="precio_normal"])').extract_first()
        ml_item['precio_internet1'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//p[@class="internet-price"])').extract_first()
        ml_item['precio_internet2'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//p[@class="offerPrice"]/text()[1])').extract_first()
        ml_item['tarjeta'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//p[@class="offerPrice"]/text()[1])').extract_first()
        ml_item['descuentos'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[@class="discount"])').extract_first()
        ml_item['codigo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space//*[@id="product"]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/p[1]/text()[2])').extract_first()
        ml_item['stock'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@class="cta-btn ajacAddToCart"]/text())').extract_first()
        ml_item['categoria'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="breadcrumb"]/a[1])').extract_first()
        yield ml_item


Aqui la respuesta:


2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: paris)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) - [GCC 5.4.0 20160609], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Linux-4.15.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'paris.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['paris.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'paris'}
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['paris.pipelines.ParisPipeline']
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-ultrahd> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-smart-tv> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-curvo-oled> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-accesorios-tv-bluray-dvd> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-monitores> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-television-todas-las-tv> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-accesorios-soportes-y-cables> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.paris.cl/store/categoria/electro-accesorios-tv-home-theater> (referer: None)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2059,
 'downloader/request_count': 8,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 8,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7356,
 'downloader/response_count': 8,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 8,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 3, 38, 1, 957792),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 9,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 52629504,
 'memusage/startup': 52629504,
 'response_received_count': 8,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 8,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 8,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 8,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 8,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 8, 3, 38, 1, 243399)}
2018-11-08 00:38:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

El sitio tiene todo el contenido en Javascript, es decir dinamicamente y eso Scrapy no lo puede manejar directamente.  Tenés que buscar en la consola del navegador, solapa red, pestaña XHR, los enlaces que devuelven el contenido en un json.  Te dejo un ejemplo:  https://www.paris.cl/store-api/catload/_search

Comment: Muchas Gracias Por la respuesta, estuve mirando donde me dijiste y cierto que resppnde un json, el problema es que como hago dinamicamente que el scrapy entre a esos json o que busque el los json, porque si tengo que decirle uno por uno cada json creo que pierde la automatizacion, es como hacerlo a mano.